# How do I calculate the probability of drawing certain cards from a deck?

Tags: probability, card-games

I have a deck of $40$ cards. They are equally numbered one to five. This means that there are $8$ ones, twos, threes, fours and fives. I will draw $5$ cards from the deck.

I want to find the probability that one of those cards is a three.

I want to find the probability that all five of the cards are threes.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. It might be useful to know why you want to know.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Do you mean "**exactly** one of those cards is a three" or "**at least** one of those cards is a three"?

Answer (score 2):

**Hypergeometric distribution** with 8 successes and 32 failures, drawing 5 items without replacement.
Let $X$ be the number of successes (3's). [I suppose you are expected to show how to get numerical answers from combinatorial symbols, and to give a rationale for answers. I'll leave the details of that to you.]

**From R:** Probabilities $P(X = 1), P(X \ge 1), P(X = 5)$
from R, where `dhyper` is a hypergeometric PDF:

```
dhyper(1, 8,32, 5)
[1] 0.4371983
1 - dhyper(0, 8,32, 5)
[1] 0.6939612
dhyper(3, 8,32, 5)
[1] 0.04221225
```

**Combinatorial symbols:**

$P(X = 1) = \frac{{8\choose 1}{32\choose 4}}{{40\choose 5}}.$

$P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 1)
=1-\frac{{8\choose 0}{32\choose 5}}{{40\choose 5}}.$

$P(X=5) = \frac{{8\choose 5}{32\choose 0}}{{40\choose 5}}.$

**Simulation.**

With 10 million iterations
one can expect two or three place accuracy.

```
set.seed(1228)
deck = rep(1:5, each = 8)
threes = replicate(10^7, sum(sample(deck, 5)==3))
mean(threes == 1)
[1] 0.4372205
mean(threes >= 1)
[1] 0.6939325
mean(threes==3)
[1] 0.0422606
```

**Bar chart** of hypergeometric distribution.

```
x = 0:3;  PDF = dhyper(x, 8,32, 3)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=3)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ cards $3$ and $40$ cards in total.

The probability to get exactly one $3$ is $p = 5\cdot \frac{8\cdot 32 \cdot 31 \cdot 30 \cdot 29 }{40\cdot 39\cdot 38\cdot 37 \cdot 36} $.

The probability to get $5$ $3$ is $p = \frac{8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{40\cdot 39\cdot 38\cdot 37\cdot 36}$.

Answer (score 0):

The second is easier. How many possible ways are there to pick a group of $5$ cards from a set of $40$? How many of these groups are all threes?

For the first, the answer is $$5\times\frac{8}{40}\times\frac{32}{39}\times\frac{31}{38}\times\frac{30}{37}\times\frac{29}{36}.$$
Can you see how each of these fractions arise?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig you're right -- I've edited my numbers